# Excel VLOOKUP show wrong results

Tags: excel, vlookup

I try to preprocess some excel documents with VLOOKUP function.

*Disclaimer: This is not real data that I need to work on, but some demo data with same problem!*
[image]

The vlookup function for left columns is

```
=VLOOKUP(B7;$D$6:$E$10;2;1)
```

and for right one is

```
=VLOOKUP(K11;$M$8:$N$13;2;1)
```

( of course, the first number is changing, B7, B8,...K11, K12, ....)

**What is wrong:**

On the left side, there appear as there is no key, but is is.

On the right side for lidija, the value should be j and not y.

I couldn't find what is wrong even though I search on the net quit a lot.

Some thinks that (it is obvious from picture and description) **I already check**:

(and it is stated as most frequent problems)

1. I lock the cells (see code above)
2. The key exist - you can see the key in table, and I do it with
   copy and paste
3. It is not a space problem (I check that none of the cells have
   space at the  end)

Comment: What is "Left side" and what is "Right side" here? Very confusing write up.

Comment: Also... not understanding what is going on here.... that last parameter of your vlookup is a `True` or `False`. `1` being `True` you are doing a "Range Lookup". Perhaps change that last parameter to `False` and see if your problem (whatever it is) goes away.

Comment: left side is starting on A7, right side is starting on j11. Yes 1 is True, 0 is False

Comment: ....you are looking for an exact match in unsorted data...so you need zero or FALSE as 4th argument - see my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using 1 as 4th argument. This is only appropriate if the lookup range is sorted and you want a "closest match"

In unsorted data, as here, for an exact match you need a 4th argument of zero or FALSE like this

`=VLOOKUP(B7;$D$6:$E$10;2;FALSE)`